# Binding IsReadOnly property of DataGridColumn depending on row

Tags: wpf, datagrid

In a datagrid I need a column whose cells are sometimes readonly

I use the bindingproxy method:

```
<local:MyDataGrid.Resources>
     <local:BindingProxy x:Key="proxy" Data="{Binding}" />
</local:MyDataGrid.Resources>
```

where Data is a custom DependencyProperty

```
public object Data
{
    get { return (object)GetValue(DataProperty); }
    set { SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
}
// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Data. 
// This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Data", typeof(object), typeof(BindingProxy),  
                          new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
```

In xaml I have:

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="MyProp"
    IsReadOnly="{Binding MyProp.IsReadOnly, Source={StaticResource proxy}"
    Binding="{Binding MyProp.MyValue, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    Visibility="{Binding Data.AnotherProp, Source={StaticResource proxy}, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"
```

The binding for `Visibility` and `Binding` works as expected.
`Data` is the viewmodel's `DataContext` and `AnotherProp` is one of its properties.

The viewmodel also has the property `public ObservableCollection<MyItem> MyItems { get; private set; }`
which is of course the `ItemsSource` of the `DataGrid` and indeed `Binding` is bound to the  properties of each single `MyItem` of each row.

This doesn't work for the `IsReadOnly` binding though. What should I do to make it work?
BindingExpression path error: 'MyProp' property not found on object BindingProxy.
This is understandable because `MyProp` does not belong to `Data`.
But why does the binding of `Binding` work?

Also `IsReadOnly="{Binding Data.MyProp.IsReadOnly, Source={StaticResource proxy}}"` of course doesn't work because `MyProp` is a property of `MyItem` and not of the viewmodel.

Also `IsReadOnly="{Binding MyProp.IsReadOnly}"` without the bindingproxy doesn't work.
Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element.

Answer (score 0):

The `Binding` property is special. It's type is `BindingBase` and it's used to apply a binding to the element that gets created in the `GenerateElement` method, i.e. you don't really bind this property to a source property. You rather set it to a `Binding` object.

If you want to bind to `IsReadOnly`, you need to use a proxy like you do when binding to the `Visibility` property.